# Returning arrays in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, function, return, subroutine

I'm working on a recursive file-finding function in Perl that's supposed to return an array of filenames. What happens, though, is when I try to print them, I just get `0`. What am I doing wrong?

```
use strict;
use File::Basename;
use constant debug => 0;

sub isdir {
    return (-d $_[0]);
}

sub isfile {
    return (-f $_[0]);
}

my $level = 0;

#my @fns = ();

sub getfn {
    my @fns = ();
    my($file, $path) = @_;
    my (undef, undef, $ext) = fileparse($file, qr"\.[^.]+$");
    $level++;
    print "-->>getfn($level): $file : $path\n" if debug;
    print "arg:\t$file\t$path ($ext)\n" if debug;
    if ($ext eq ".bragi") {
        open my $FILE, "<", "$path/$file" or die "Failed to open $path/$file: $!";
        my @lines = <$FILE>;
        close $FILE;
        foreach my $line (@lines) {
            chomp($line);
            my $fullpath = "$path/$line";
            print "---- $fullpath\n" if debug;
            if (isfile($fullpath)) {
                #print "file:\t$fullpath\n";
                push(@fns, $fullpath);
                getfn($line, $path);
            }
            elsif (isdir($fullpath)) {
                #print "DIR:\t$fullpath\n";
                opendir my ($dh), $fullpath or
                    die "$fullpath does not exist or is not a directory: $!";
                my @files = readdir $dh;
                closedir $dh;
                foreach my $f (@files) {
                    getfn($f, "$fullpath");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    print "<<--getfn($level)\n" if debug;
    $level--;
    #print @fns;
    return @fns;
}


foreach my $f (<*>) {
    #print "fn: ".$f."\n";
    my (undef, undef, $ext) = fileparse($f, qr"\.[^.]+$");
    if ($ext eq ".bragi") {
    print &getfn($f, $ENV{PWD})."\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at File::Find::Closures? You might not need to do any work, or very little work by stealing code from it. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main problem here is that a line like this:

```
getfn($line, $path);
```

doesn't really do anything. It finds all the files in the subdirectory, but then it completely discards them. You need to incorporate its return value into your outer call's `@fns`.

A second problem is that this:

```
print &getfn($f, $ENV{PWD})."\n";
```

forces the returned array to be treated as a scalar, so it prints the *number* of array elements rather than the *contents* of the array elements. You probably want something like this:

```
print "$_\n" foreach getfn($f, $ENV{PWD});
```

Comment: `print &getfn($f, $ENV{PWD}),"\n";` perhaps. The concatenation will cause the scalar context, comma will preserve list context. Nice catch.

Comment: Is there any reason why you've added the `&` to the front of the subroutine calls? It's my understanding that that are rarely needed in Perl 5, but perhaps this is an obscure case that I'm missing.

Comment: @davorg: I haven't. The only `&` in my answer is in code that I was commenting on, that I had copied from the question. (That said, if I were writing this program, I would probably define `getfn` as `sub getfn($$) { ...`, and then I'd include `&` in the recursive calls only, just to bypass the warning about the unchecked prototype.)

Answer (score 1):

You never assign the returned array to anything when you call `getfn()` recursively. Your only assignment is:

```
my @fns = ();
```

at the top of the function, and that's what is getting returned.

Comment: Can't I print it instead of assigning it?

Comment: Wait no I push elements to it

Comment: This is wrong. `print @array` will print all the elements of the array, separated by whatever value `$,` is set to (default ""). E.g. "foobarbaz". It will **not** print the number of items in the array, unless you do `print scalar @array` or similar technique to impose a scalar context. ruakh spotted this, that concatenation with `.` does impose scalar context, and that's your error.

Comment: Yeah, my perl is rusty off the top of my head, forgot the concat caused the scalar to print.